# How can I detect when my UITextView is being edited and then call an action?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextview

When my UITextView is being edited, I want a button to appear. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implemetn `UITextViewDelegate` in your class and when editing is being started on `UITextView`
it'll call it's `textViewShouldBeginEditing:` function where you can do whatever you want. You can show your button when editing start and hides when editing ends in this function.

```
– textViewShouldEndEditing
```

For further detail [see this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html)

Answer (score 2):

i will detail above answer a little bit:

YourViewController.h

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

YourViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.yourTextView.delegate = self;

}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
   // do smth like create a button 
   return TRUE;
}
```

Read [Apple manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewShouldBeginEditing%3a) for more

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [UITextViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html). If you set your UIViewController to be the `delegate` of the UITextView, it will be sent `textViewDidBeginEditing:` and `textViewDidEndEditing:`. You can show/hide your button when you receive those messages.

Answer (score 0):

//in view did load.

```
UITextField entered1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120.0, 85.0, 150.0, 25.0)]; 
[entered1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 
[entered1 addTarget:self action:@selector(example:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:entered1];
[entered1 release];
```

or

```
  [textfieldname addTarget:self action:@selector(example:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        .........
  }
  -(IBAction) example:(UIControl *)sender
  {
   //your code here.
  }
```

Comment: The question was about `UITextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6.4, iOS 8.4, ARC Enabled

Don't make my mistake, took me a long time to figure it out, but I was adding...

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

because I am used to working with UITextField's, but obviously we need...

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

Hope this saves someone time.  Cheers!